# How can I encrypt with cryptoJS and decrypt with openssl?

Tags: encryption, cryptojs, php-openssl

Hi in the backend which is written in PHP we have the following function for decryption

> openssl_decrypt($myMessage, 'AES-256-CBC',
> 'myKeyPlainText', 0, 'myVIplainText');

both key and vi are in plainText.
I want to encrypt my message in front end using Javascript. I use CryptoJS and the code is the following

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, 'myKeyPlainText, {
    iv: 'myVIplainText,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
});
```

I always get false from openssl_decrypt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [CryptoJS's documentation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input) says "For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV." You'll have to find out how it's deriving the key and IV and replicate that logic in your OpenSSL code.

Comment: ... although from the same documentation it looks like OpenSSL command-line will accept the same strings, so there probably is OpenSSL support for this already somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with this

Comment: In the CryptoJS code you have to pass key and IV as `WordArray`, e.g. if key and IV should be Utf8 encoded: `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(<your key/IV string>);`